# Alternative software to generate family tree like Descendant tree in Gramps?

Tags: family-tree, gramps, chart-type

Is there any other software that generates family tree like the [Descendant tree](https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Gramps_4.1_Wiki_Manual_-_Reports_-_part_4#Descendant_Tree) in [Gramps](https://gramps-project.org/)?

> This report generates a chart of people who are descendants of the starting person. Alternatively it may generate a chart of descendants of the parents of the starting person.

Here an example of Descendant tree (from the Gramps wiki):

[image]

Comment: Gramps is free and open source, so I think you should specify whether being free and open source is a requirement or optional for you.

Comment: I suggest that you remove this image as it contains information about living people. Use an alternative image where no living are shown.

Comment: I've replaced the image put by @PolyGeo (already taken from the gramps site) with another from gramps examples without living people.

Comment: The image in the question is similar to the Descendancy View in FamilySearch FamilyTree.  https://www.familysearch.org/blog/en/family-tree-views/

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if you are looking for a horizontal descendant tree or just alternatives to printing out a descendant tree other than using Gramps itself. I am going to focus on alternatives to built in charting like what would be in Gramps, FamilyTreeMaker, Mac FamilyTree, etc. as well as point out which ones do horizontal trees.

Depending on which platform you are on there are alternative options with each application having its own charting options.

When I was a FamilyTreeMaker user on Windows many years ago I supplemented their lack of charting with [Progency Genealogy Software](http://progenygenealogy.com/). When I switched to Mac they did not have a Mac version and I found that [MacFamilyTree](http://www.syniumsoftware.com/macfamilytree/) has almost all of their charts built into the core program. It also had several descendant trees/ancestor trees and I really like the double sided ancestor tree.

I am not necessarily recommending one over the other.. just informing of options I am aware of to accomplish your needs.

Mac Family Tree's Horizontal:
[image]

One of the chart's in Progency's Software top/down and horizontal.
[image]
[image]

[Web Family Tree](https://learnforeverlearn.com/ancestors/) I recently discovered and it is a hybrid tree that is editable using GED file and is free at this time.

[image]

WebTreePrint can do these:
[image]

GedScape has Horizontal and Top/Down Charts
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I am not a Gramps user and am trying to get my head around the chart that you are showing. I cannot see how Allan Davies links to anyone on that chart. Perhaps you can explain it and explain exactly the type of descendant chart you are looking for.

I use Family historian and this is a section of a descendant diagram from that.
[image: Family Historian Sample]

All of the genealogy programmes I have used over the years have produced descendant charts. It may be worth exporting your data from Gramps and trying the free / free trial versions of the other programmes on the market to see if there is one that suits your needs.

There are also specific charting programmes like Legacy Charting or PAF Companion (if it is still available).

Comment: In the example chart Allan Davies is married first with Annie Allens and then  with April Adams. Your chart looks more like the one I'm looking for.